# Progress bar gets null when trying to add progress

Tags: java, progress-bar, progress

This bar is used to show the user the progress of the URL to IP conversion, basically you input a list of website url's and it will convert them into IP Addresses, this all works perfectly however on a long list it can take a few seconds which is why I am adding a progress bar.

I've used a progress bar before to give the user a percentage of download completed however in this case it doesn't seem to like the value I give it. If I print the value it prints correctly for example,

```
20 
40
60
80
100
```

While printing

```
System.out.println(Progress.percentage);
```

However when I try to set a new string or a new value for the progress bar it crashes.

```
try {
    Progress.main(null);
    Progress.totalToDo = IPArray.size();
    for (String URL : IPArray) {
        URL url = new URL(URL);
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(url.getHost());
        String temp = address.toString();
        String IP = temp.substring(temp.indexOf("/") + 1, temp.length());
        URLArray.add(IP);
        Progress.percentage = (URLArray.size() * 100) / Progress.totalToDo;
        Progress.ipProgress.setString(Progress.percentage + "%");
        Progress.ipProgress.setValue(Progress.percentage);
        result += IP + System.getProperty("line.separator");
    }
    IPFrame.textAreaIP.setText(result);
    GEOLookup.check(IPFrame.textAreaIP.getText());
}
```

If you require any more information don't be afraid to ask, appreciate any help.

EDIT:
Sorry forgot to post the error it prints, I know that the error is caused by

```
Progress.ipProgress.setString(Progress.percentage + "%");
Progress.ipProgress.setValue(Progress.percentage);
```

because once removed the application proceeds fine. Error that's printed is below.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.elvazar.ipgrabber.IPGrabber.convert(IPGrabber.java:86)
    at com.elvazar.ipgrabber.IPFrame.jButton4ActionPerformed(IPFrame.java:335)
    at com.elvazar.ipgrabber.IPFrame.access$700(IPFrame.java:23)
    at com.elvazar.ipgrabber.IPFrame$8.actionPerformed(IPFrame.java:125)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: Did you set "stringPainted" to true using ".setStringPainted(true)" on your progressBar object ? Otherwise, your string won't appear on the bar. You should have a look at "BoundedRangeModel" too, in order to update the value.
In other words, just take a look at the Javadoc. (Who said RTFM ? ;)) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JProgressBar.html#setValue(int)

Comment: Yes I did. However even if I hadn't then it wouldn't print an error just wouldn't update? Which also reminds me, I should post my error.

Comment: What is the class of the Progress object btw ? The NPE could come from the ".set" methods on ipProgress, are you sure that ipProgress!=null ?

Comment: Progress is a class, the progressbar is named ipProgress. I am referencing the ipProgress from Progress into IPgrabber.

Comment: If you are sure that it is caused by the lines you showed, then I'm sure that's because the set methods are applied on a null reference. Check if ipProgress is null, using a debugger e.g.

Comment: It is possible it is using a null reference, this is because it has no super. How would you go about this if this was the case?

Comment: Actually if ipProgress==null, it's because you didn't initialize the reference to an object. Are you sure that you initialized ipProgress (ipProgress = new JProgressBar() e.g.) ?
PS : forget about the super thing, it's a static class right ? No object instance of the class and no super then.

Comment: Yes it's a static class and its referenced statically, also ipProgress = new javax.swing.JProgressBar();

Comment: `ipProgress` seems to be null. Is the `IPGrabber.convert()` code the one inside the `try` block?

Comment: No, the try code displayed is within the convert() method.

Comment: Could you post the whole code ? That would be a lot easier than trying to guess what's behind this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it, had to invoke it with an event queue. Thanks for all the feedback.